# WF4 Business Rules

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I want to pass a object to workflow as input parameter, without creating instance of it, as this object is already filled up with lot of sub-objects, and I want to run lot of rules on that object.  I want to use
WorkflowInvoker.Invoker(this);  Is this possible in Windows Workflow Foundation 4.0, If so, what should I keep in InArguments as the type?
Thanks In Advance,

Comment: You want to pass an object without creating it.  That makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input....

Sorry, I think I haven't kept the question correctly, I had a business class used by bank customers, class is like this, 
    public partial class BankName.DTOS.clsCardDetails : BaseClass
    {
               public string _mBankStatusCode;
               protected override string IsCreditCard(HttpContext ctx)
               {
                       Status = ctx.Request.Form["Trans_Status"];
                       _mBankStatusCode = Status.ToString();
               }
    }

Now, I have to pass this class object to workflow foundation, I should not create new instance of this class in workflow again. Because in workflow, I want to get the status, so ideally what I thought of passing to workflow is object of "BankName.DTOS.clsCardDetails". That is my question.

InArguments<> to workflow is object of BankName.DTOS.clsCardDetails

Answer (score 0):

Arguments passed into a workflow need to be put into a dictionary and the dictionary is passed into the workflow.

```
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "BankName", _bankNameObject } };

    WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(this, dictionary);
```

The key must have the same name as your InArgument and your object must have the same type as your InArgument.
You can pass as many arguments as you like into the workflow via the dictionary.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/05/26/passing-arguments-to-workflow-activities-again.aspx